# How to reuse a function from an existing Cypress test, and call it in a new one?

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, cypress

I have the following function, which is inside a parent function.

```
// A function that creates a random string and will later pass this to a variable
function generate_random_string(string_length) {
    let random_string = '';
    let random_ascii;
    for(let i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
        random_ascii = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + 97);
        random_string += String.fromCharCode(random_ascii)
    }
    return random_string
}

var random_string = generate_random_string(6)
```

I have many uses for this random string generator, inside of other test files for different scenarios. Instead of having to copy and paste this each time, I want to reuse this function and call it inside another test file.

How should I set this up?

I tried to create a custom command inside the `commands.js` file like so:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("random_string_gen", 
    function generate_random_string(string_length) {
      let random_string = '';
      let random_ascii;
      for(let i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
          random_ascii = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + 97);
        random_string += String.fromCharCode(random_ascii)
      }
      return random_string
})
```

But this didn't work when I called it inside my test file:

```
cy.get('#name').click()
cy.get('#name').random_string_gen()
```

I want to reuse the function inside one file, and call it inside another, but I am not sure how to set up the necessary command/index JS files, so a template to get me started would be really helpful!

Comment: Can you put it into separate `.js` module, and `import` or `require` inside your test?

Comment: Also, see https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Best-Practices

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just create a custom command on your `cypress/support/commands.js` like this:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('generate_random_string', (string_length) => { 
  let random_string = '';
  let random_ascii;
  for(let i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
      random_ascii = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + 97);
      random_string += String.fromCharCode(random_ascii)
  }
  return random_string
 });
```

Then, on your test spec files you can call `cy.generate_random_string(5)`.

For example, this will print to the console a random generated string with a length of 5.

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

context('stackoverflow', () => {
  it('stackoverflow', () => {
    cy.generate_random_string(5).then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  })
})

// Output: eauyy
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much @diogo! Appreciate your answer

Comment: Thanks @diogo. Quick clarification - can we create functions rather than custom command and use in same way as custom command as you have shared example above?

Comment: Yes @GaganShrestha e.g. `export function typeText(selector, text) {
  return cy
    .get(selector)
    .type(text);
}`

Comment: When I used the above function and use it in cypress test to enter email address, I am getting only one letter typed from the above function instead of specified length.  Cypress.Commands.add('generate_random_string', (string_length) => { 
    let random_string = '';
    let random_ascii;
    for(let i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
        random_ascii = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + 97);
        random_string += String.fromCharCode(random_ascii) 

    return random_string+ '@gmail.com'
}
   });

Comment: cy.generate_random_string(8).then(random => {
            cy.get('#emailSignup').type(random)
          })