# random generated string function in command.js is not getting recognized in e2e loginTest.js - Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I copied this code below and have it in my support/command.js. I am using the following function to create multiple username for login functionality using Cypress JS.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('generate_random_string', (string_length) => { 
    let random_string = '';
    let random_ascii;
    for(let i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
        random_ascii = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + 97);
        random_string += String.fromCharCode(random_ascii) 

}

  return random_string+ '@gmail.com'



   });
```

Then, In my loginTest.Spec, I am calling it like below

```
const {commands} = require('../support/commands')

const { Input } = require("@angular/core")
const { wrap } = require("module")
const { isExportSpecifier } = require("typescript")



describe('our first suite', () => {

    it('first test', () => {
        cy.visit('/')
        cy.get('a[data-tracking-name="Sign up for free"]').click()
        cy.get('.flex').should('contain',"Create your free account")
        cy.get('[for="emailSignup"]').should('contain',"Work email")

        // cy.get('#emailSignup').type(generate_random_string(5))
        cy.generate_random_string(5).then(random => {
            cy.get('#emailSignup').type(random)
          })
        // cy.get('#emailSignup').type("John18002@gmail.com")
        cy.contains('button', 'Continue').click()
        cy.get('#fullName').type('IamTest User')
        cy.get('#password').type('AHJQ*234')
        cy.get('[type="submit"]').click()
        cy.window().then((win) =>  {
            cy.stub(win,'alert').as('alert')


        })

        cy.get('.flex').contains('Close').click()



    })
})
```

I am getting generate_random_string is not defined message. I tried creating a new file under support with the above function and tried importing in commands.js and then use it in the loginSpec file but even that didn't work. Using web based automation tool almost after 6 yrs and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **TLDR** is custom commands don't return values the same way functions do.

If you want to use it like this

```js
cy.get('#emailSignup').type(generate_random_string())
```

then it should be a plain function, not a custom command.

```js
const generate_random_string = (string_length) => { 
    let random_string = '';
    let random_ascii;
    for(let i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
        random_ascii = Math.floor((Math.random() * 25) + 97);
        random_string += String.fromCharCode(random_ascii)
    }
    return random_string + '@gmail.com'
}
```

If you want to keep it as a custom command, use it like this

```js
cy.generate_random_string(10).then(random => {
  cy.get('#emailSignup').type(random)
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I want to use it as the custom command. I replaced my code to the one below but getting a message saying cy.type() cannot accept an empty string. You need to actually type something.. I have updated my code above. Thanks for your help. Am I  missing any imports?

Comment: I'm getting something back when I pass in the `string_length` parameter (nothing when I leave it out). But the result is a bit gobbledygook so I think there's something wrong with the content of the custom command. Where did you copy it from?

Comment: Also it's missing the "@" which should be in a well-formed email.

Comment: So, move the gmail bit down to the last line: `return random_string + '@gmail.com'`

Comment: From here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54559089/how-to-reuse-a-function-from-an-existing-cypress-test-and-call-it-in-a-new-one

Comment: Fixed the missing @ and passed in the string length as '5' but only letter 'U' was typed

Comment: With string length 5 I get `curvj@gmail.com`

Comment: Are you are literally passing in '5'?

Comment: yes, 5, not with quotes. Not sure why it is not working :(.

Comment: You could paste the updated code into the question, I can check it.

Comment: The `return random_string + '@gmail.com'` needs to go down a bit - below the closing bracket of the `for() {...}` loop. That's why you only get 1 char in the email, it returns before the loop completes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works.. Appreciate your help.